# Requirements management data

Tags: machine-learning, software

[Requirements management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_management) software produces data (either stored on a database server or as individual files). Export to CSV is also usually supported.

Where can I get this data for real-life projects? I actually need the software specification data/document which is created at the end of requirements phase.

Both proprietary or open source software are OK, as long as they have a proper requirements phase.

Comment: I made your question on-topic, it was being closed for being unclear and of-topic. "just like software-artifacts infrastructure repository which hold faults, test cases and scripts of open source software?": Is it a metaphor? Or are you really looking for test cases and scripts? Also, you wrote "real time", did you mean this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing I guess you just mean real-life, alive projects?

Comment: Maybe nobody uses such software?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul i am actually looking for the intial requirements that are stated by the customer to create a new software.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul by meaning real time, i just want to emphasis that the artifact must state the initial requirements of softwares created by companies or open source. i just dont want artifacts of student projects etc...

Comment: i actually need  the software specification document which is created at the end of requirements phase